# Beginner DJ software compatible with Macbook Pro 2021 (Apple M1 chip processor)

Tags: audio, music, apple

I just got a new Macbook Pro 2021, which I understand uses the Apple M1 chip processor. I am trying to start mixing electronic music as a hobby, and an acquaintance of mine who DJs told me that they had not heard of any compatibility issues with basic DJ software and newer Macbooks. Unfortunately I did not research it further.

I just attempted to install Traktor DJ 2 on my new computer but was unable to, and it seems to be connected to compatibility problems due to the M1 chip. I have since heard from someone else that this may be an issue with other DJ software as well. Taking up this hobby is a high priority for me as it's been something I've wanted to do for some years and is a central motivator in my purchasing a new computer. As such, if it will be hard to get working free/low cost software that is compatible with my computer, or if my options will be very very limited, I would be completely willing to return my new Macbook and purchase a 2020 model that still runs off the old Intel chip processor. My question is twofold:

1. Can you recommend any specific DJ software that would be compatible with a Macbook Pro 2021 and good for beginners, for standalone use? Or, can you recommend a resource for figuring this out? I am seeking free software for starters but could be interested in recommendations for low cost paid software as well.
2. If you have an overall sense of the field in this regard (beginner DJ software and recent Macbooks), do you think I would be best off to just return my new Macbook and get a 2020 model that uses the Intel chip processor?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.